# Wrong number of values when importing csv file in Weka tool

Tags: java, csv, dataset, weka

I want to open a CSV file (saved from OpenOffice calc) in weka.
I keep getting an error: " wrong number of values. 120 read, 110 expected on line 4." 
 The csv was already fixed with quotes around the labels. And I count 120 values on the first lines. 
I have removed all the possible symbols(, ; " = + -) possible. 
Still the problem persists.

Comment: You should include the relevant code in the question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20051481/wrong-number-of-values-when-importing-csv-in-weka . you might need to reffer the link