# Weka load CSV file error

Tags: csv, weka

In this time I can't load my file.
I was able to read the file before.
I do not know what is happening from XLS to CSV.
But now read when the following error:

Read 44,expected 41,read Token[EOL],line 3 degree or concentration

Here's my code Line 1 to Line 4

```
ID,gender,age,tall,weight,BMI,BMI-test,Waist-circumference,Waist-circumference-test,cornea-error,Lens-error,cataract-error,Artificial-crystal,Optic-nerve-abnormalities,glaucoma,Macular-degeneration,Refractive-error,Conjunctivitis,Retinopathy,High-intraocular-pressure,Anterior-chamber-narrowing,Presbyopia,B12,T4,cortisol,tsh,hb-aic,hdl-c,ldl-c,High-blood-sugar,Triglycerides-high,Cholesterol-high,Hyperuricemia,smoke,drunk,Betel-nut,sport-frequency,denture,brush,milk,Five-fruits-and-vegetables,,,
1,female,80,146.2,61.3,28.67911393,heavy,92,fat,,1,1,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,H,,,,,1,no-smoke,no-drink,no-betel,third-fifth,some-denture,third-bursh,,eat,,,
2,male,93,157.6,68.6,27.61923781,heavy,90,,,1,1,,,,,,,,,,1,,,,H,,,,,,,,no-smoke,no-drink,no-betel,third-fifth,some-denture,morning-and-night-bursh,drink,eat,,,
3,male,96,170.4,53,18.25310234,,74,,,1,1,,,,,,,,,,1,H,,,,,,H,,,Cholesterol-high,,no-smoke,seldom-drink,no-betel,third-fifth,no-denture,third-bursh,,eat,,,
```

Thank for everybody help.

I'm sorry I can not describe my problem completely.
I use Weka to read a CSV file.
Previously used no similar problems.
I will EXCEL output into a CSV file and did not make any changes

Comment: What code are you using to read the file? Taking a shot in the dark here, perhaps it's flummoxed by the empty line in the data file? Have there been code changes or changes to this file between when it was working and now?

Comment: I'm sorry to have trouble with you. I've modified my question.

Comment: @Dc47dc   Did you get this to work?  Did the answer below solve your problem?

Comment: @G5W Yes,I did. Thank for everybody help.

Comment: @Dc47dc  - if the answer solved your problem, it would be good if you accepted and upvoted the answer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20051481/wrong-number-of-values-when-importing-csv-in-weka

Answer (score 0):

I have a guess. The error says 'read 44, expected 41'. Your CSV export has 44 columns. My guess is that Weka expects there to only be 41, so it doesn't know what to do. Check the configuration of the importer to see how many columns it's expecting to find.

And I'd delete that blank line. That can't be helping.

Comment: Thank you mroach. I was directly from the EXCEL output into CSV files. I do not know why it turns into 44 instead of 41 for my data.
I will delete the blank line, thank you for the reminder.