# How to i escape a single quote in a csv file for weka reader?

Tags: csv, weka

How to escape something like Coeur D'Alene in weka?
 
Im trying to convert a csv to arff to do some prediction but it keeps giving me this error

```
Wrong number of values. Read 4, expected 24, read Token[EOL], line 7393 Problem encountered on line: 7393
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wrong number of values when importing csv in Weka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20051481/wrong-number-of-values-when-importing-csv-in-weka)