# Problems when uploading a csv file to weka

Tags: excel, weka

My original file is in the .xlsx extension and through Excel I change it to the .csv extension (comma delimited file) I do the process of changing the extension and I have no problems, when I try to upload it to the weka software I follow the process to upload it but it throws me the following error.

I attached the image of the error:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdtCy.png)
I also leave the link of my csv file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mgTQ4fADFDD0cd_QzTj8F-TzOpR5EqlA/view?usp=sharing

I looked for the problem, investigating it tells me that it is an error because there are characters that weka cannot read but I look in the line that tells me weka and I can't find anything strange, I also tried searching and replacing rare characters that the naked eye can't see but no find any rare characters.

Comment: Line 9115 has the string `Chris O'Grady`, I suppose that this is seen as a quote to start a string. Therefore all fields after that name are no longer seen as separate fields but as part of the string. So either actually quote the string, i.e., `"Chris O'Grady"`, or escape the `'`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wrong number of values when importing csv in Weka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20051481/wrong-number-of-values-when-importing-csv-in-weka)

Comment: Replace the character with a blank space and it already allows me to upload the csv, thanks